# How to deduce array size out of std::array<T, N>::pointer member/dependent type?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++14

My goal here is to write safe replacement for `strcpy` for case when destination buffer size is known during compilation, and I would like for buffer size to be deduced, so user won't need to know it. For example:

```
char xs[2] = { 0 };
strcpy(xs, "abc"); // buffer overflow!
printf("[%s]\n", xs);
```

Output for this will (hopefully) be:

```
[abc]
```

For simple case, when C-style array is passed, it can be written without much fuss:

```
template<size_t N>
char * safe_strcpy(char (& dst)[N], const char * src) noexcept {
    std::snprintf(dst, N, "%s", src);
    return & dst[0];
}
```

Size of array is deduced, snprintf takes care of placing terminating null byte, voilà.

I can sort-of adapt it to std::array as well:

```
template<size_t N>
typename std::array<char, N>::pointer
safe_strcpy(std::array<char, N> & dst, const char * src) noexcept {
    std::snprintf(dst.data(), N, "%s", src);
    return dst.data();
}
```

But this version is not really a drop-in replacement:

```
std::array<char, 2> ys = {};
strcpy(ys.data(), "abc"); // overflow!
safe_strcpy(ys, "abc");   // ok, but I needed to remove .data()
```

I want following case to work ok:

```
safe_strcpy(ys.data(), "abc"); // "a" should appear in buffer
```

dependent type of `ys.data()` is `std::array<char, 2u>::pointer {aka char*}`, so I think it should be possible to deduce array size out of this, but I can't figure out how :/

When I try something like this:

```
template<size_t N>
typename std::array<char, N>::pointer
safe_strcpy(typename std::array<char, N>::pointer & dst, const char * src) {
    // etc...
}
```

compilation fails with error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘safe_strcpy(std::array<char, 2u>::pointer, const char [4])’
safe_strcpy(ys.data(), "abc");
                            ^
(...)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘N’
```

I tried with gcc 5.1.1 and clang 3.5.0, error in both is essentially the same. Is it possible to deduce type out of dependent type in C++ at all?

[edit]
to all you kind people saying, that I should use std::string - you're missing the point here. I could've written same question with any STL container and `::iterator` instead of `::pointer`.

Comment: Not possible, sorry.

Comment: Seriously? But compiler knows this type (it's printing it in error message even...).

Comment: `{aka char*}`, so `safe_strcpy` only see `char*`.

Comment: The compiler knows the type at the point you wrote the call, but it does not know the type within the function.  The extra information is just there for debugging -- `.data()` *is* a `char*`.  The compiler error message is saying "this `char*` comes from this type expression", but that is not the name of the type.

Comment: From `char*`, you cannot possibly deduce whether that is `std::array<char,2>::pointer` or `std::array<char,3>::pointer`. However, you could conceivably create a `sized_pointer`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44c24a8463b6673b

Comment: @PatrykObara, why don't you just make an overload that takes `std::array` without the `.data()` part? Then you would be able to deduce the size.

Comment: @ChrisBeck I did and it is even shown in question ;) Question was from my curiosity, since I don't understand why compiler doesn't deduce type when given dependent type (to me it looks like arbitrary rule placed in language without good reason, this looks like simple pattern matching to me). I was not given good answer yet, but supposedly this is described in C++ Standard 14.8.2.4/4 (this describes what a "nondeduced context" is; in my example `std::array<char, N>` is nondeduced).

Comment: The "c++ way" is `std::string` and streams btw. - instead of the C library.

Answer (score 1):

The `data()` member of the `template<class T> array` in namespace `std` is -according to the C++11 standard- declared as follows

```
T * data() noexcept;
const T * data() const noexcept;
```

but not like this:

```
pointer data() noexcept;
const_pointer data() const noexcept;
```

Even if it had been declared using the typedef there is no difference. Consider your example code:

```
std::array<char, 2> ys = {}; // 1
strcpy(ys.data(), "abc"); // 2
safe_strcpy(ys, "abc"); // 3
```

#### // 1

Compiler instantiates `std::array<char, 2>`. Which makes the typedef `pointer` = `char*` and compiles (if ever used) a imaginary member `pointer data()` with the following signature:

```
char* data();
```

The typedef is substituted because typedefs and alias names are syntactic sugar for the programmer - not the compiler. The compiler knows that this is `char*` so there it is.

#### // 2

You call the template using (as your first argument) a function that has the signature `char*(void)`. (And again `std::array<char,2>::pointer` is not a type of its own but `char*`). Therefore, the call is `void(char*, char const*)` and this is what the compiler is trying to deduce the template from. And this call does not exhibit any information about the array size, nor does it even know about the fact that the pointer comes from an array in the first place.

#### // 3

Here your call is

```
void(std::array<char, 2> &, char const *);
```

and the compiler can deduce size and even character types if required.

Comment: OK, in this case you're right, but (2) is only partial answer; even if `std::array<T,N>::pointer` were a real type (subclass in `std::array<T,N>` and not merely a typedef) - matching would still fail (with exact same error). That's because C++ standard (14.8.2.4/4) says, that everything before `::<type>` is "nondeduced", and compiler won't even try to match it. I am disappointed in C++ yet again :(

Comment: @PatrykObara: For `std::array` it is not only partial but you're right that `N` would be non-deducible even in case of a class type following `std::array<T, N>::type`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is that `std::array<char, N>::pointer` is `char*` *for all `N`*, so when you call `ys.data()` you pass a `char*` to the function and there are infinite`N` that all match. This the compiler fails it as ambiguous. I took a look at `array` and I can't see any way to create a drop-in replacement that you're looking for.

But since you're writing C++ you *can* solve the problem just by using `std::string` instead of trying to deal with C-strings.

Answer (score 0):

As others said there is no pointer member in `std::array` that has the information about the size, specially `pointer` doesn't have that information.

**A very non portable** alternative is to use `._M_elems` instead of `.pointer` in GNU C++.

```
int main(){
  std::array<double, 10> arr;
  assert( std::extent<decltype(arr._M_elems)>() == arr.size() );
}
```

Should `std::array` have a standard `carray` and `carray_type` member? perhaps yes. Although this variable will decay so easily in a pointer that it won't be very useful.